# django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1426, "Too big precision 1000

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-2.7, django-templates

I get the folling problem when I try to run python2.7 manage.py syncdb on webfaction.  Apologies if I am not providing the right info as I am very new to this.

```
Creating table carts_cartitem
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/user/webapps/myproject/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/user/webapps/myproject/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/user/webapps/myproject/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/home/user/webapps/myproject/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/user/webapps/myproject/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 533, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/home/user/webapps/myproject/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 27, in handle_noargs
    call_command("migrate", **options)
  File "/home/user/webapps/myproject/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 115, in call_command
    return klass.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "/home/user/webapps/myproject/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/user/webapps/myproject/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 128, in handle
    created_models = self.sync_apps(connection, executor.loader.unmigrated_apps)
  File "/home/user/webapps/myproject/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 239, in sync_apps
    cursor.execute(statement)
  File "/home/user/webapps/myproject/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 81, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/user/webapps/myproject/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/user/webapps/myproject/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/home/user/webapps/myproject/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 63, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "/home/user/webapps/myproject/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 128, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 174, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1426, "Too big precision 1000 specified for column 'line_total'. Maximum is 65.")
```

Comment: The error, and what to do to fix it are right there in the last line of the stack trace. You have a property value that is out of range for the `line_total` field on your model.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You are much more likely to receive help with your problem if you include a [minimum, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and you desired and actual inputs.

Comment: I still don't understand this, the only thing I have figured out is that I can get it to run perfectly on local host in sqlite3 but when I try with mysql on webfaction I get the error.  Does this give any clue as to where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Please excuse my lack of knowledge here, I seemed to have solved this by running python manage.py migrate --fake and now I am no longer getting any of the previous errors.